# PHP Redirect after posting to Database

Tags: php, sql, redirect

I'm using this code ...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE notes SET Note=('$_POST[note]')
WHERE UserID='19'");

mysql_close($con);
header('Location: editrem3.htm'); //clears POST
}
?>
```

How do I redirect the page after the user clicks on submit and the data has been posted?

Comment: Doesn't it work the way you are doing it already?

Comment: uhhhhhhm isnt that what thats doing?

Comment: Are any errors occurring (do you have error output enabled)?  Have you output anything prior to this code?

Comment: Try moving the header statement out of `if` body.

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection/database escaping.

Comment: Yeah, i'm only starting to learn about PHP and SQL. where should i put the header?

Comment: I've got it working now. I didn't have the PHP code at the very top of the page, I had the <html> tag in front of it. So all good now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you are entering into the `if()` condition by `echo` ing something inside the `if()` block.

If it's working correct, then make sure that you've sent NOTHING before the `header()` is executed. Because when you use `header()` in a PHP file, there MUST NOT be any other output statements before that. So, check for any HTML code or `echo`s before it.

Then if you are sure that `header()` is being executed, and still it's not redirecting, make sure that the target file exists.

Extra: ALWAYS add `exit()` immediately after `header()` redirects. Else the code will continue executing and can reveal your sensitive data.

Comment: I've got it working now. I didn't have the PHP code at the very top of the page, I had the <html> tag in front of it. So all good now thanks.

Comment: you're right, if you're calling headers, you can't because headers we're already sent, i guess you should've had some errors on screen (given they weren't suppressed or something).

Answer (score 1):

Using the relative path to the file is probably causing issues. Try it using the full path (also probably outside the if{} would make more sense).

PHP might be able to parse the relative path, but [the w3 spec explicitly states to use absolute URIs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

edit: To elaborate, handing a relative path off to a browser for redirect is playing with fire. The browser might think it knows where it is in your site's hierarchy, but it might be actually in a different spot.

Also, if you're not getting a 404 page or something similar, then the relative path *might* not be your issue, but it might help you later on down the road

Comment: Actually relative path has nothing to do with PHP, it's client's responsibility to handle redirects

Comment: @galyymzhan - The relative path can be interpreted differently by the various browsers, making it the developer's responsibility to control the paths as much as possible. If you're referring to me talking about PHP 'parsing the path', then perhaps my use of 'parse' was wrong - I didn't mean it literally.

Answer (score 0):

use meta redirects, something like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

but you could do something like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php">
```

works fine with me